# swapping between hex digits in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string, hex, swap

I have some string data that I need to swap it like this:

My string data for example: 056446A750513300
what I need to form  is this : 00335150A7466405

I think that you guys noticed the pattern (each two least significant digits moved to be the most significant ones and so on)

I need an algorithm or a code that can implement this swapping really fast in VB.NET. 
and I have one more question >> in this case does my string data also work as a hex data without any conversion ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You make it fast by *not* swapping the digits but reading them in reverse order, two nibbles at a time.  And of course by not getting them in the wrong order in the first place.  You cannot get accurate "make it fast" advice if you don't show how the string is being used.

Comment: Please show what you have attempted and where you are having problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `StringBuilder`

```vb
Imports System.Text
```

```vb
Dim input = "056446A750513300"
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
For i As Integer = input.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
    sb.Append(If(i Mod 2, input(i - 1), input(i + 1)))
Next
Dim result = sb.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the StrReverse Function.... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e462ax87(v=vs.90).aspx

```
Dim TestString As String = "056446A750513300" 

Dim revString As String = StrReverse(TestString)

' revString now equals "003315057A644650".
```

Comment: This took a few seconds to seach in search engine.... you really should try and do some work!

Comment: Did you test this?  This code gives 003315057A644650 which is not what the OP wanted.  Compare to the desired result:  00335150A7466405

Answer (score 0):

Ok... now that I've read the question....

```
    Dim InitialStr as String = "056446A750513300"
    Dim OutputStr as String

    Dim HexValues as String()
    For x = 0 to InitialStr.length/2
        HexValue(x) = Mid(InitialStr, x*2, 2)
    Next

    For x = InitialStr.length/2 to 0 step -1
        OutputStr += Hexvalue(x)
    Next

    'OutputStr now equals "00335150A7466405"
```